# Implement onPropertyChanged on property in all pages

Tags: c#, maui

I'm binding an activity indicator to a property called IsLoading to show that the page is busy (e.g. processing API calls). I need to implement this in all my MAUI app pages, so my question, how can I re-use this code? The property is implemented as follows:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool isLoading; 

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get => isLoading;
            set
            {
                isLoading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {

            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Create a base class that all pages or view models inherit from that defines that property

Comment: Thank you for the response, can you maybe provide a sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to put this in a base class that you inherit from. For example.

1. Create a class/file `BaseViewModel.cs`, of course the name can be whatever you want. It might look like this:

```cs
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isLoading; 

    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get => isLoading;
        set
        {
            isLoading = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

2. Now, whenever you create a new view model, you need to inherit from this. Let's say that you create a `EditPersonViewModel`, that would look like this:

```cs
public class EditPersonViewModel : BaseViewModel // This is where you inherit from the BaseViewModel
{
    private bool isSaved; 

    public bool IsSaved
    {
        get => isSaved;
        set
        {
            isSaved = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have access to all the things that are also in `BaseViewModel`. So you can set `IsLoading` to true or false, or you can implement a new property, `IsSaved` in my above example, and you can still call `OnPropertyChanged` to make the UI aware of the value change.